# UIBezierPath not rendering properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, nib

I have a tablviewcell which has uiview in it.
Based on some logic I change the background color and make the left and right corner rounded.

I make these view corner round from cellForRowat indexPath function.

Here is my extension.

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

and how I use it

```
cell?.myCustomView.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomRight,.bottomLeft], radius: 10.0)
```

Its working fine when width of iphones is 375,
but it fails to update for device with width greater than 375.

And after scrolling the tableview, it again stretches back correctly to the desired width.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: One option is to just set the layer’s `cornerRadius` and (if targeting iOS 11 and later) its `maskedCorners`. If you’re going to use this `mask` approach, you have to update the mask in `layoutSubviews` (a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383286/1271826).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to update the path when the view changes size. In `cellForRowAt` the cell has not yet been fully laid-out by auto-layout.

So...

Create a `UIView` subclass for your "rounded corners" view (simple example):

```
class RoundedCornersView: UIView {

    var corners: UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner()
    var radius: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Now, anytime the view changes size - such as on first use or device rotation, for example - the view will automatically update the path.

Here is how you would use it in a table cell. In Storyboard, set the class of the "background view" to `RoundedCornersView`

```
class RoundedCornersView: UIView {

    var corners: UIRectCorner = UIRectCorner()
    var radius: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}

class MyTestCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var myCustomView: RoundedCornersView!

}
```

Then, in `cellForRowAt`:

```
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTestCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTestCell

        if shouldBeRounded {
            cell.myCustomView.corners = [.bottomRight, .bottomLeft]
            cell.myCustomView.radius = 10.0
            cell.myCustomView.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            cell.myCustomView.corners = []
            cell.myCustomView.radius = 0.0
            cell.myCustomView.backgroundColor = .white
        }

        return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    selectedView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 12.0)
}
```